# object context menu

Tags: mesh, interface

I was wondering how I can bring back the object menu table after it disappears. When I add an object this object menu appears, but if I click somewhere else it disappears and I can't find a way to bring it back as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, it cannot be *'brought'* back.
Also, according to my knowledge, there is no workaround for this. You need to do the adjustments in the beginning only.

**Edit (thanks to @John Eason):**
If you have just clicked away from the object (or even selected another object) and not done anything else, you can press <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up the adjustment dialogue again.

Comment: As long as you haven't done anything apart from clicking away from the object, you can use F9 to bring up the adjustment dialog again.

Comment: I added a few words to your edit - only if somebody thinks, selecting a different object is doing "anything else" (although it's basically just clicking away from the object)...

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann thanks for the edit. I was about to go out when I answered that so it was done in a rush! :^)